# Why has the number of profile views been removed from MSE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

The number of profile views of each user is no longer visible. Why has this been removed from MSE?

[image: My profile]

Comment: A related announcement on [meta.se]: [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285). (Already with score below $-100$, so it wasn't received too well.)

Comment: Ok,@MartinSleziak Thanks for the link.

Comment: I am displeased with this (network-wide) change, and I wonder if MSE can revert back to the old version.

Comment: @Joe  i am also displeased .Old  version was awfully good.

Comment: Is there now an alternative way to roughly gauge a user account's (a) age and (b) recency of activity? Merely reducing the precision of this info, and/or adding an option for users to hide it... would *actually* have been an improvement.

Comment: @RyanG You can see such data in the [accounts tab of the network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/267077/martin-sleziak?tab=accounts). (This is mentioned in [John Omielan's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive/368289#368289) to the question linked in my first comment.)  Also using [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) you can find values of the data [in the Users table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677) at the time when the database was updated the last time.

Comment: Here are examples of such queries [for a single user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1444589/data-about-a-user?userid=8297) and [for several users](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1444590/data-about-the-given-users?list=8297,85306).

Comment: Also for those who have the mobile app, the number of views and last seen are still retained.

Comment: I didn't even notice. This happened recently, not during my "sabbatical"? I do look at profiles, but mostly I'm interested in the questions or answers someone has posted. Speaking only for myself, I find the number of profile views not very meaningful or interesting.

Comment: @RyanG You can see oldest question/answer, no? Oldest comment?

Comment: @RedBanana Yes to oldest post—although Martin's suggestion right under my comment supercedes this. (As for oldest comment, I'm unaware of any comments-search or comments-history-by-user on MSE.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a network wide change announced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/231933). Site moderators are unable to revert changes to the software, so math.se can't get it back unless it comes back for everyone (which seems unlikely).

Answer (score 6):

A bit long method but it would help you to see Last Seen, profile views and member since then you can open [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410627/14212297) and click on Copy Snippet To Answer and then replace the second line with

> const params = "?order=desc&site=Mathematics&filter=!40D72h-7nG92Z1_td";

Then run the snippet and you can see all the three Features.

For reference-

[image]

Comment: I recall staff from SE mentioning that it was mostly a vanity metric. Through SQL code and other kinds of codes it is still possible to retrieve that. In any case, I agree with SE staff to remove all kinds of useless vanity metrics and focus more in content of questions and answers.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, **showing "last seen" is *not* a vanity metric**.  Many of us use it quite frequently.  In particular, it is extremely useful when deciding whether to respond to a comment (or even a question).  If the person hasn't been seen for years, it would be a waste of time; if they are still active it would be a good thing to do.

Comment: Like I said, you can still access that and other metrics though SQL code and other scripts. For the majority of users who post and answer questions, those numbers are irrelevant.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, still access yes, but too much trouble to be worth my bother.  There will (and already has been) a reduction in my responses.

Comment: @RayButterworth: you say you use them frequently, so it should not be an obstacle to use SQL scripts (which are more powerful as you can get as many records as you want). I know of many external researches that get record from MSE in their studies of the size as a social network. If you are here just to question and answers I don't see the need to het those metrics. It may be contra as invasion of privacy.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, I never said it would be "an obstacle". I said it would no longer be worth the effort.  Before: one click to see and one click to return. After: use SQL scripts.

Comment: @OliverDiaz  I disagree with you about useless vanity metrics

Comment: @jasmine: That was the determination of SE staff. I am no employed by SE or its affiliates. In any event, if you are doing research about SE (or MSE for that matter) there are tools to get all kinds of info. If you are a user who like me is only interested in helping others with questions, and posting questions, that metric and other metrics such as reputations, lats-time seen, years of membership, etc are irrelevant.

Comment: But  some  time ,   i find it helpful  whether  i have to comment on an answer or not.  suppose that the user is not active  then it will be useless to write comment on their answer @OliverDiaz

Comment: I need the vanity metrics as an affirmation of my self-worth.  Now that I can no longer see how many people have looked at my page, I must rely on my rep score and that mysterious influence metric to get myself out of bed in the morning.

Comment: @RonGordon: Is the fact that you earned the "populist" badge any consolation? :)

Comment: @Joe No. I am inconsolable.